# Manipulating form of output redux

Tags: expression-manipulation

To clarify the question that I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92401/manipulating-output-of-polynomial-expansion), I have the following question:

I am generating a very large term  by the following:

```
n = 2;
permut = Permutations[Range[n]];
yIntegrationvariabes = Table[{y[i], -∞, ∞}, {i, 1, n, 1}];

list = {};
Do[list = Append[list, y[i]], {i, 1, n, 1}];

functionwhole[i_] := 
  Sum[(j - 1)*y[j], {j, 1, n, 1}]*
    Sum[(k - 1)*y[permut[[i,k]]], {k, 1, n, 1}]
      Exp[
        Collect[
          -Sum[
             (B + Conjugate[B])*y[h]^2 - 
               2*μ[h]*(B*y[h] + Conjugate[B]*y[permut[[i,h]]]), 
             {h, 1, n, 1}], 
          list]]

poly = Sum[functionwhole[p], {p, 1, n!, 1}] // Expand;

list2 = {};
Do[list2 = Append[list2, y[i] y[j]], {i, 1, n, 1}, {j, i, n, 1}]
poly2 = Collect[poly, list2]
```

This generates the following expression for `poly2`:

> ```
> E^((-B - Conjugate[B]) y[1]^2 + (-B - Conjugate[B]) y[2]^2 + 
>   y[2] (2 Conjugate[B] μ[1] + 2 B μ[2]) + 
>   y[1] (2 B μ[1] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[2])) y[1] y[2] +
> E^((-B - Conjugate[B]) y[1]^2 + (-B - Conjugate[B]) y[2]^2 + 
>   y[1] (2 B μ[1] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[1]) + 
>   y[2] (2 B μ[2] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[2])) y[2]^2
> ```

This outcome may be considered in *Mathematica* to be a list and certain components may be selected by accessing it in the following way:

```
pol2[[1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

yielding

> ```
> (-B - Conjugate[B]) y[1]^2
> ```

I will be performing some operations on `poly2` by accessing its elements in a similar manner. To do so, I need to be able to re-express the outcome of `poly2` such that each element in the exponent has the term B to appear *before* the `Conjugate[B]` term, i.e. instead of the outcome shown above for `poly2` I would like the following output:

> ```
> E^((-B - Conjugate[B]) y[1]^2 + (-B - Conjugate[B]) y[2]^2 + 
>   y[2] (2 B μ[2] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[1]) + 
>   y[1] (2 B μ[1] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[2])) y[1] y[2] +
> E^((-B - Conjugate[B]) y[1]^2 + (-B - Conjugate[B]) y[2]^2 + 
>   y[1] (2 B μ[1] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[1]) + 
>   y[2] (2 B μ[2] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[2])) y[2]^2
> ```

which is of course the same, but with the B terms always appearing before the Conjugate[B] terms in each parentheses. How could I achieve this for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: You should edit your previous question rather than add a new one.

Comment: Although you certainly can access parts of a polynomial through `Part` as you show, I would be concerned that this is a very brittle method that depends on the polynomial taking a very specific `FullForm` representation.

Comment: Voting to close. Please edit your previous question instead of posting a new one. Thanks a lot

Comment: The remaining question can now be posed quite simply as how do we tell mathematica to order something of the form `Conjugate[B] x[1] + B x[2]` so that the `B` term is first.  Unfortunately I think the answer is you will end up pulling all your hair out if you don't learn to live with the way mathematica wants to order things.

Comment: It seems it this case, if you can live with it, if you make the change `mu[1]->mu1,mu[2]->mu2` (etc) that changes to pecking order of the symbols enough that the order comes out the way I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mountain of a mole hill. Just because you can see a difference in the two orderings doesn't mean *Mathematica* can.

Consider the following expressions.

```
MatchQ[(2 Conjugate[B] μ[1] + 2 B μ[2]), (2 b_ h_[2] + 2 Conjugate[b_] h_[1] )]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Position[μ[2]] /@ 
  {(2 Conjugate[B] μ[1] + 2 B μ[2]), (2 B μ[2] + 2 Conjugate[B] μ[1] )}
```

> ```
> {{{2, 3}}, {{2, 3}}}
> ```

This shows the internal representation of the two forms are identical. So it seems to me any expression manipulation you wish to do on your forms can proceed as if all of them were written in the way you prefer, because the front-end will automatically transform any input in your preferred form into *Mathematica*'s canonical form.